# Do the Dashing Hero's "borrow a move" moves work like multiclass moves?

Tags: multi-classing, dungeon-world

That is, when you pick a move using Anything You Can Do... or ...I Can Do Better that relies on other moves to work (such as the Wizard's Cast A Spell move), do you get the other moves too, like you would if you picked it using a multi-class move?

Anything You Can Do...

> When you Make Camp, 
>   choose one move another player knows and gain hold equal to the number 
>   of bonds you have with that player. You can spend 1-hold to use that move. 
>   When you Make Camp,lose any remaining hold from this move.

...I Can Do Better works the same way, except the move is unlimited-use, and you spend the hold for bonuses when using the move.

Comment: Can you quote the Anything you can do... and ...I Can do better moves in the question? Dashing hero isn't part of the core game and despite having played in a party that had one I haven't studied the move sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It would not level like the multiclass advanced moves would

Multiclass advanced moves give you a spell-casting level in that class that levels up everytime you levelup, increasing in power. However Anything you can do... has no text leading it in that direction at all. Thus you would always just be casting a spell at level 1.

## From a narrative perspective it makes no sense.

The dashing hero is modeled on the old pulp heroes of swashbuckling and old film stars like Errol Flynn.  Anything you can do... is an interpretation of the hero's ability though pure grit to mimic the abilities of those around him and just bluff his way through life. Magic however is something either innate or learned though study (based on other DW classes) and from that standpoint a Dashing hero watching a wizard cast a spell doesn't mean he'd be able to.

Comment: Concerning spells there are 2 things I'd consder: first, whether or not to be able to copy spell-related moves should be depending on the world you play in: high magic world where basic magic is easy to learn by everyone? -> go for it! A world where magic is reserved for those with innate power -> don't!   Second thing is: I would take the move Spellbook literally: you start with three fist  level spells, and if you level up while you have the move, proceed to level up proceed to add a  new spell of your level or lower to the spellbook. When you replace the copied move with another, restart.

Comment: You said the second move was unlimited use, does that still make it reset mandatorily when making camp?

Comment: And yes, following what Joshua mentioned about the character pretending stuff, that very much fits the narrative: the character is able to bluff the simplest of spells, but will not achieve higher levels of skill.

Comment: @gatherer Yeah, Dashing Hero isn't really the class for Kvothe. He's more a solo Bard who MC'd rogue, hit level 10, switched to Wizard, and maybe more. "How do I make Kvothe (at level 1)?" might be a good question though.

Comment: Please stop the world from spinning I'd like to get off... In all honesty theres going to be some DM discretion involved when you're interfacing 3rd party classes with the core classes even more so when its a 1 3rd party class affecting another as you are suggesting with the namer.

Answer (score 1):

### "Cool, what's that look like?"

The Dashing Hero is doing something during the camp that allows them to copy a move. Rules As Written this is not a multiclass poach and as such disables starting move chains that would all be required to work together, like Born of the Soil - Studied Essence - Shapeshifter or Spellbook - Prepare Spells - Cast A Spell.

But given that there's nothing in the rules stopping them from picking up **Ritual** under these circumstances, it seems like ultimately the real barrier is the feasibility of why and how the Dashing Hero can pull off the copy in the first place.

Of course, it'll be up to the GM how it actually comes off. Here's what I think is reasonable:

**Cleric/Wizard: Cast a Spell.** The Dashing Hero has no caster levels, and so can prepare rotes (minus any spells that are rotes because of cleric or wizard racial features) and a first-level spell that the Cleric or Wizard could prepare. Unlike the Cleric and Wizard, they cannot break for an hour to reprepare forgotten spells.

**Cleric: Divine Guidance.** This one's interesting. Can the Dashing Hero believe in the Cleric's deity? Do they follow a faith of their own, but never gave its god or gods anything that they might be repaid? It could break either way.

**Druid: Shapeshifter/Spirit Tongue.** Interesting for the same reason as Divine Guidance. Can the Dashing Hero understand the Druid's land? Do they discover a deeper connection to their own native soil?

**Ranger: Command.** It's probably a little more sensible that the Dashing Hero can also work with the Ranger's animal companion, circumstances permitting, than that they temporarily cow some passing wild creature into doing a couple of tricks and vanishing.

Answer (score 0):

On page 29 of the rulebook it is stated, that for the purpose of multiclass moves, any starting class moves that depend on each other count as one move.

As your question regards a custom class, it is up to interpretation if the author intended such use.

However, as some moves would be rendered useless then, I suppose that the same logic as to multiclass moves should apply. At least I would rule that way as a GM.

Concerning spells there are two things I'd consder: first, whether or not to be able to copy spell-related moves should be depending on the world you play in.
High magic world where basic magic is easy to learn by everyone? -> Go for it! 
A world where magic is reserved for those with innate power -> Don't!
This should be on the part of the GM and the group together to decide.

Second thing is: I would take the move Spellbook literally: you start with three fist level spells, and if you level up while you have the move, proceed to level up proceed to add a new spell of your level or lower to the spellbook. When you replace the copied move with another, and then take Spellbook again, restart from scratch with an empty spellbook.

Comment: I realised i interpreted the question incorrectly. Please do provide the exact wording of the move in question.

Comment: I edited my answer. But this question might be too opinion based and I highly reccommend contacting the author of the class about his intention.

Comment: Many people write classes that they publish and there are lots of well appriciated classes out there. I do not know that particular class or who wrote it, though. Everything not in the rulebook I consider a custom class.

Comment: Downvoters please provide feedback.